# How to display new data after form submit and form validation HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and JavaScript so i was trying to do a simple task in which i have a form and i am performing validation of email and password,and if all validation pass, i want to display the details (removing earlier form body).

This is I have tried so far but cannot figure out how to run validation and show new data after clicking on submit button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form action="#" name="myForm" id="myForm">

            <br>email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></br>
            <span id="emailText"></span>

            <br>password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></br>
            <span id="passText"></span>
            <br/>

            <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="return validation(); document.getElementById('container').style.display='none'">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="new_container">
        <p id="display_email"></p>
        <div id="Btn"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validation(){
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

            // Email validation
            if(email == ""){
                document.getElementById("emailText").innerHTML = "Email cannot be empty";
                document.getElementById("emailText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            if(email.indexOf('@') <= 0){
                document.getElementById("emailText").innerHTML = "Email is not valid";
                document.getElementById("emailText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            if(email.charAt(email.length-4)!="." && email.charAt(email.length-3)!=".") {
                document.getElementById("emailText").innerHTML = "Email is not valid";
                document.getElementById("emailText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }

            // password validation
            if(pass == ""){
                document.getElementById("passText").innerHTML = "Password cannot be empty";
                document.getElementById("passText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            if(pass.length < 6 || pass.length >= 20){
                document.getElementById("passText").innerHTML = "Password length should be greater than 5 and less than 20";
                document.getElementById("passText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            showDetails();
        }
    
        function showDetails(){
            document.getElementById('container').style.display='none';
            // email
            const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            document.getElementById("display_email").innerHTML = `Email: ${email}`;

            // creating confirm button
            let button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "confirm";
            // appending the button
            let body = document.getElementById("Btn");
            body.appendChild(button);
        }
    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now if i click on submit button, validation works as expected but i cannot display the email while removing previous form (like i did display='none' inline).

Comment: Check out [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) - You will be able to replace the contents of an element. `textContent` is also better that `innerHTML` unless you need HTML tags.

Comment: you do not remove your form, if you want to show previous form just add document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN no, i want to remove the old form when i click on submit and display new div with id new_container. Right now when i click on submit only validation takes place but then nothing happens.

Comment: I would suggest using event listener and calling the functions separately through the click event

Comment: Well you are not invoking the showDetails function in your code. Add the following at the end of validation: `showDetails();`. Does that work?

Comment: @AbrarHossain yes got it working now ! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Change following Code

```
 <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="validation()">submit</button>


  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

  document.getElementById('container').style.display='none';
```

this may solve your problem..

Full Code Here...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form action="#" name="myForm" id="myForm">

            <br>email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></br>
            <span id="emailText"></span>

            <br>password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></br>
            <span id="passText"></span>
            <br/>

            <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="validation()">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="new_container">
        <p id="display_email"></p>
        <div id="Btn"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validation(){
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;

document.getElementById('container').style.display='none';

            // Email validation
            if(email == ""){
                document.getElementById("emailText").innerHTML = "Email cannot be empty";
                document.getElementById("emailText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            if(email.indexOf('@') <= 0){
                document.getElementById("emailText").innerHTML = "Email is not valid";
                document.getElementById("emailText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            if(email.charAt(email.length-4)!="." && email.charAt(email.length-3)!=".") {
                document.getElementById("emailText").innerHTML = "Email is not valid";
                document.getElementById("emailText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }

            // password validation
            if(pass == ""){
                document.getElementById("passText").innerHTML = "Password cannot be empty";
                document.getElementById("passText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            if(pass.length < 6 || pass.length >= 20){
                document.getElementById("passText").innerHTML = "Password length should be greater than 5 and less than 20";
                document.getElementById("passText").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            showDetails();
        }
    
        function showDetails(){
            // email
            const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            document.getElementById("display_email").innerHTML = `Email: ${email}`;

            // creating confirm button
            let button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "confirm";
            // appending the button
            let body = document.getElementById("Btn");
            body.appendChild(button);
        }
    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```